# generating HTML (bootstrap cards) from AJAX call to JSON file when some cards have images and some don't

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am using Shuffle.JS, here is the javascript that generates the cards:

```
function getMarkupFromData(dataForSingleItem) {
   var blogtitle = dataForSingleItem.blog_title
   var blogtext = dataForSingleItem.blog_text
   var blogimage = dataForSingleItem.blog_image
   var blogbutton = dataForSingleItem.blog_url
   var categories = dataForSingleItem.blog_tags
   var blogdate = dataForSingleItem.date
   return [
     '<div class="js-item mb-4" style="width: 22rem;" data-groups=' + categories + ' data-date-created= '+ blogdate +' data-title="'+ blogtitle + '">',
     '<div class="card w-100">',
     '<img class="card-img-top" src="' + blogimage +'">',
     '<div class="card-body">',
     '<div class=js-item__details>',
     '<h3 class="card-title bold">' + blogtitle + '</h3>',
     '</div>',
     '<p class="card-text">' + blogtext + categories + '</p>',
     '<a href="' + blogbutton + '" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>',
     '</div>',
     '</div>',
     '</div>'
   ].join('');
 }
```

This works fine but the issue is that some of the JSONs do not have images as they are just a title with text. What is the best way to do this? If I keep the image value/key empty in JSON it will still generate the img class line with then shows a card with missing image.

So how do I generate the HTML as above, but so that if blog_image is missing, it does not generate that img line.

Comment: Have an `if` that checks blogimage is missing or not. If it is return markup without the `<img>` else return what you have right now.

Comment: Yea I thought about that, any tips on where to learn how to write that? I'm completely new to javascript. Would I have to write an entirely new return statement? I guess I could check outside the statement using if, but how do I then inside the return write that part of HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underneath all your vars, before the return:

```
if (blogimage === null) { // Depending on what comes back from JSON just check if it's empty/null/length is 0
    // return markup without <img> tag
}
else {
    // return markup you have now
}
```

Comment: the { at the end of your if statement is a typo yea? Trying it now

Comment: No, it closes the `else`

Comment: But there three { and only one }? if { {, else { } ?

Comment: Sorry yeah the second `{` needs to be `}`, edited it

Comment: No trouble just double checking

Comment: One more question, instead of just having no key:value inside of json, what if I had "blog_image":null, would that guarantee it returns a null?

Comment: I think if there is no key:value pair it will return undefined, in that case check for undefined. If you have control of what the JSON returns and want to put null go ahead and check for null in the if statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171168/discussion-between-alexis-drakopoulos-and-vincent-nguyen).